# Launching simulator in atom throwing error

Tags: appcelerator, atom-editor

[ERROR]  Unable to find Info.plist in root of specified app path

The atom could not find the info.plist in the 'app' in my build folder.

Answer (score 0):

I sloved this issue by switching the xcode path using 'sudo xcode-select -switch {Xcode-path}' command in terminal.
Here xcode is the culprit.